# Certain faces refuse to be selected, yet others on the same object slect fine

Tags: modeling

Certain faces refuse to be selected (as the arrows points to), yet others on the same object select just fine as you can see by the one face on the bevel edge that is selected. What am I overlooking!?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried clicking on/near the center dot of the face?

Comment: Ahhh.. LOL That worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the way Blender detects selection, for large faces you sometimes need to click on or near the selection dot in the middle of a face to select it.

[image]